# Passing Textbox Input as a Parameter in Code Behind OdbcCommand

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

The goal is that as a user I can enter a string into a text box. That string is passed to the codebehind as a parameter to a stored procedure call and returns an alert in the window.

The following code is not executing the stored procedure or returning an alert.

Markup:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function PageLoad() {
            document.getElementById('<%= ValueHiddenField.ClientID%>.value' = '<%= RemoveTote_TextBox.ClientID%>')
        });
    </script>
    <div id="RemoveToteForm" runat="server" class="col text-center">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col text-center">
                <h2><%: Title %></h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="RemoveTote_TextBox" runat="server" />
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" name="SubmitButton" value="Submit" onclick="PageLoad()" />
        <asp:hiddenfield id="ValueHiddenField"
              onvaluechanged="ValueHiddenField_ValueChanged"
              value=""
              runat="server"/>
    </div>

</asp:Content>

Code Behind:

protected void ValueHiddenField_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string ntsh = ValueHiddenField.Value;
            using (OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectToClient"].ConnectionString))
            {

                OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("{call usp_Remove_Tote (?)}", con);

                OdbcParameter Tote_number = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Tote_number", OdbcType.Char);
                Tote_number.Value = ntsh;
                con.Open();
                String result = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                con.Close();

                if (result != "Success+")
                {
                    Response.Write("<script>alert('" + result + "'); </script>");
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Write("<script>alert('" + result + "'); </script>");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Changing the value of field in Javascript will not trigger the server side event. You want to execute some C# code when user changes value in TextBox?

Comment: I want the C# code to run onclick of the Submit button. The way I am currently trying to achieve that is by onclick of the Submit button my HiddenField is changed. And onchange of the HiddenField my C# method is called. Both the markup and codebehind are above. I am open to other ways of achieving the functionality of a user enters a string into the textbox that on click of a button calls a C# method and uses the textbox string as a parameter.